# How can dynamically change fieldLabel of a Textfield in Ext Js 4?

Tags: extjs

I'm, trying to display textfield label attribute based on a combobox selection.For that i wrote a change listener for combobox and on the listener i,m checking combox value and based on this i have to change fieldLabel property of textfield. Following is the code,

```
                         textfield:

                                 xtype:'textfield',
                                 id:'firstName',
                                 fieldLabel: 'Billing',
                                name: 'firstName',
                                maxLength: 30,
                                enforceMaxLength :true
```

combo-box listener method,

```
listeners:{
                                    change:function(field, newValue, oldValue)
                                    {   
                                        if(newValue == "billing")
                                        {
                                           var firstName = Ext.getCmp('firstName');     
                                           firstName.fieldLabel = 'Billing'
                                        }
                                        else if(newValue == "shipping"){
                                            var firstName = Ext.getCmp('firstName');
                                             firstName.fieldLabel = 'Shipping'
                                        }
                                        else if(newValue == "recipient"){
                                            var firstName = Ext.getCmp('firstName');
                                             firstName.fieldLabel = 'Receipient'
                                        }
                                    }
```

While debugging this code i can see that the field value is assigning to the fieldLabel attribute but its not reflecting in the UI. Shall i miss something here ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `setFieldLabel();`

Comment: i have tried this method , but its not working , i,m getting an error that this method is undefined , i,m using extjs 4.0.0 and i tried this with version 4.2.1 , and i found that 'setFieldLabel()' method is available in this version.

Answer (score 4):

Define the textfield in a variable like

```
var tf = Ext.create('Ext.form.TextField',{
    fieldLabel: 'Billing',
    name: 'firstName',
    maxLength: 30,
    enforceMaxLength: true
});
```

and then in your change listener have something like this

```
tf.labelEl.update(newValue)
```

I could test this on 4.1.1, but not on 4.0.0, but i think it should work. Here is the jsfiddle for working example - http://jsfiddle.net/jaykhimani/xLn8p/

Comment: Ext.getCmp('textfield_id').labelEl.update('updated_name'); works for me on Ext 4.2